# How to INCLUDE php files in nested folders

Tags: php, file, directory, include

I am new to php and facing initial problems :).

My directory structure is as follows :

```
site
   index
      homepagesections.php
   assets
       css
         style.css
   config
      db.php
   include
      header.php

index.php
```

In the index.php , which is in the root folder I need to include the header.php file which includes config/db.php and also assets/css/style.css.

I have tried all the options ( including. the **DIR** option ) but failed. What is the best way to include these files and also the path for the style.css ?

Comment: Please show the code you're having trouble with.

Comment: Sure will do if I am unable to find the solution with the answers.

Answer (score 0):

In index.php path to header is include/header.php:

```
include('include/header.php');
```

In header your path to db.php is ../config/db.php so you will have:

```
include('../config/db.php');
```

Note '../' - this is how you navigate 1 level up, from the directory your file is. In header adding css will be something like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/style.css">
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am doing the same but failed. So I tried __DIR__ function but that also failed. Can you explain me what exactly the "include" command is doing ? What I exactly mean is that if 'include' command is something like cut n paste then when I include a php file in index.php then that code is pasted in index.php ? And if included file also includes a file then that file code is also pasted in index.php ? If it is so then I have to use the path from the index.php file position. Kindly advice.

Answer (score 0):

In index.php:

```php
include (__DIR__.'/include/header.php');
```

In header.php:

```php
include (__DIR__.'/../config/db.php');
include (__DIR__.'/../assets/css/style.css');
```

Comment: Thanks. Can I use the include command for style.css also ?

Comment: @Kumar Basically yes, you can inline it like this `<style><?php include (__DIR__.'/../assets/css/style.css'); ?></style>`. Whether this is a good practice or not is a matter of discussion.

Comment: The issue is still unresolved :(. I will post the complete code very soon for better communication. Thanks.